# Taking screenshot on TEST FAILURE in ITESTListener

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to automation and was trying to take a screenshot automatically whenever a test fails.
I also want to include this screenshot in extentreports. My program is working properly when there are no failed test cases. Whenever there is a failed testcase, the program is not running properly.

## This is TestBase class

This class incldues

#Initializing the driver  
#Before Method  
#After Method  
#Method to take schreenshot

```java
public abstract class TestBase {
    public  WebDriver driver;

    public static Properties prop;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void loadPropertiesFile()
    {
        prop = new Properties();
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\anoop\\IdeaProjects\\QAGURU\\TutorialsNinjaProject\\src\\main\\java\\com\\tutorialsninja\\config\\config.properties");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            prop.load(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not loaded");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public WebDriver initializeBrowser()
    {
        String browser = prop.getProperty("browser");
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge"))
        {
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        return driver;
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void openBrowserWithUrl()
    {
        driver = initializeBrowser();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));

    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void teardown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public String getScreenshot(String testName, WebDriver driver)
    {
        TakesScreenshot takesScreenshot = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File screenshot = takesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String screenshotPath = "C:\\Users\\anoop\\IdeaProjects\\QAGURU\\TutorialsNinjaProject\\screenshot" + testName +".png";
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot,new File(screenshotPath));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Takes Screenshot is null");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return screenshotPath;

    }

}
```

## This class includes the test cases

I am purposefully failing "verifyloginWithInvalidCredentials" test and my goal is to take screenshot and include it in the extent report

```java
public class LoginTests extends TestBase {


    @Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "Valid LogIn Data", dataProviderClass = DataProviders.class)
    public void verifyloginWithValidCredentials(String[] login) {
        HomePageBeforeLogin homePage = new HomePageBeforeLogin(driver);
        homePage.clickLoginOption();
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.login(login[0], login[1]);
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPage.loginValidation());
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifyloginWithInvalidCredentials() {
        HomePageBeforeLogin homePage = new HomePageBeforeLogin(driver);
        homePage.clickLoginOption();
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.login(Utilities.generateEmailWithTimeStamp(), "vispedafsgardi@gufum.com");
        String actualWarningMessage = "Warning: No match .for E-Mail Address and/or Password.";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualWarningMessage, loginPage.getWarningMessage());
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void verifyloginWithInvalidEmailAndValidPassword() {
        HomePageBeforeLogin homePage = new HomePageBeforeLogin(driver);
        homePage.clickLoginOption();
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.login(Utilities.generateEmailWithTimeStamp(), "vispegardi@gufum.com");
        String actualWarningMessage = "Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or Password.";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualWarningMessage, loginPage.getWarningMessage());
    }

    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void verifyloginWithValidEmailAndInvalidPassword() {
        HomePageBeforeLogin homePage = new HomePageBeforeLogin(driver);
        homePage.clickLoginOption();
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.login("vispegardi@gufum.com", "123vispegardi@gufum.com");
        String actualWarningMessage = "Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or Password.";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualWarningMessage, loginPage.getWarningMessage());
    }

    @Test(priority = 5)
    public void verifyLoginWithoutProvidingCredentials() {
        HomePageBeforeLogin homePage = new HomePageBeforeLogin(driver);
        homePage.clickLoginOption();
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.clickLogin();
        String actualWarningMessage = "Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or Password.";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualWarningMessage, loginPage.getWarningMessage());
    }
}
```

## This is my MyListeners class that implements ITestListener

```java
public class MyListeners extends TestBase  implements ITestListener {

    ExtentReports extentReport;
    ExtentTest extentTest;
    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {

        extentReport =  ExtentReporter.generateExtentReport();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result)
    {
        String testName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        extentTest = extentReport.createTest(testName);
        extentTest.log(Status.INFO,testName + " Started Executing");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        String testName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        extentTest.log(Status.PASS,testName + " got successfully executed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        String testName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        try {
             driver = (WebDriver) result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getDeclaredField("driver").get(result.getInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("driver not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String screenshotPath = getScreenshot(testName,driver);

        extentTest.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
        extentTest.log(Status.INFO,result.getThrowable());
        extentTest.log(Status.FAIL,testName + " got failed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {

        System.out.println(result.getName() + " skipped");
        System.out.println(result.getThrowable());

    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {

        extentReport.flush();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedWithTimeout(ITestResult result) {

    }


}
```

## This is testng xml file I am running

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel Test Suite" thread-count="5"  >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.tutorialsninja.listeners.MyListeners"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="C:/Users/anoop/IdeaProjects/QAGURU/TutorialsNinjaProject">
        <classes>
            <!--<class name="com.tutorialsninja.testcases.RegisterTests"></class>-->
            <class name="com.tutorialsninja.testcases.LoginTests"></class>
           <!-- <class name="com.tutorialsninja.testcases.SearchTests"></class>-->
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

This is the significant part of the error message I am getting. The driver is null. The tests works properly when there are no failed tests. Whenever the test is failed I am getting this error and the flow of execution is stopped.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: driver
      at com.tutorialsninja.listeners.MyListeners.onTestFailure(MyListeners.java:50)
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: driver
      at com.tutorialsninja.listeners.MyListeners.onTestFailure(MyListeners.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs(org.openqa.selenium.OutputType)" because "takesScreenshot" is null
      at com.tutorialsninja.base.TestBase.getScreenshot(TestBase.java:82)
    at com.tutorialsninja.listeners.MyListeners.onTestFailure(MyListeners.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the driver field is defined in the same class where the test methods are present (LoginTests in this case). If the driver field is defined in a different class, you'll need to make it accessible to the MyListeners class.

Modify your onTestFailure method in the MyListeners class as follows:

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    String testName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
    Object currentClass = result.getInstance();
    WebDriver driver = ((TestBase) currentClass).driver;  // Access the driver from the current test class

    String screenshotPath = getScreenshot(testName, driver);

    extentTest.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
    extentTest.log(Status.INFO, result.getThrowable());
    extentTest.log(Status.FAIL, testName + " got failed");
}
```

By accessing the driver from the current test class, you can ensure that it is not null and can be used to capture the screenshot and include it in the extent report.

Hope this helps.